# Using awk for a report by gathering counts of (sub)instances

Tags: awk, report

For this data set (data.csv; actually a couple of hundreds lines long)

### Input data

```
mig|Lecture|12.00
mig|Other|1.681
mige|Research|20.026
mige|Other|4.32
mige|Lecture|0.120
migc|Research|12.83
migc|Lecture|2.170
migc|Other|70.719
done|Research|24.794
done|Lecture|23.123
done|Other|9.96
done|NoMigration|6.9
mig|Research|5.4
md|Required|0.169
md|Required|0.02
mdc|NoMigration|0.122
mdc|Research|0.019
md|Required|2.12
mdc|Research|1.23
mdc|Other|18.53
mdc|Other|2.08
mdc|Lecture|2.5
```

I want to get a report with the columns "status", "category", "nodes", "quota".

### Data dictionary

- *status*: this can be `done`, `md`, `mdc`, `mig`, `migc`, `mige`
- *categories*: `Other`, `Lecture`, `Research`, `NoMigration`
  (`NoMigration` only applicable for the status `done` and `mdc`)
- *nodes*: should count all instances of the category according to the status (expecting an integer).
- *quota*: This is the sum of the *nodes*-count, in respect of the category and the status.

### Wrong output

Currently I get this back

```
done|Lecture|4|64.777
mdc|Lecture|6|24.481
md|Lecture|3|2.309
migc|Lecture|3|85.719
mige|Lecture|3|24.466
mig|Lecture|3|19.081
```

### awk code

Here is the awk snippet:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS="|";OFS="|" }{
           nodes[$1]++;     # Increment count of lines.
           quota[$1] += $3; # Accumulate sum of second column.
        }
            END{for (x in nodes) {
        printf("%s|%s|%.f|%.3f\n",x, $2, nodes[x], quota[x]) | "sort";}}' data.csv
```

The problem is to get the *categories* according to the *status*....

### Desired output

The desired output should look like
It should look like this (abbreviated):

```
done|Research|1|24.794
done|Lecture|1|23.123
done|Other|1|9.96
done|NoMigration|1|6.9
md|Required|3|2.309
mdc|NoMigration|1|0.122
mdc|Research|2|1.249
mdc|Other|2|20.61
mdc|Lecture|1|2.5
mig|Lecture|1|12
mig|Other|1|1.681
mig|Research|1|5.4
migc|Research|1|12.83
migc|Lecture|1|2.17
migc|Other|1|70.719
mige|Research|1|20.026
mige|Other|1|4.32
mige|Lecture|1|0.12
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [multidimensional array](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Multidimensional.html) `nodes[$1,$2]` and print the values in the END part.

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS="|";OFS="|"}
{
  nodes[$1,$2] += $3
  quota[$1,$2]++
}
END { 
  for (i in quota) {
    split(i, val, SUBSEP)
    print val[1] OFS val[2] OFS quota[i] OFS nodes[i] | "sort"
  }
}
' data.csv
```

Output

```
done|Lecture|1|23.123
done|NoMigration|1|6.9
done|Other|1|9.96
done|Research|1|24.794
mdc|Lecture|1|2.5
mdc|NoMigration|1|0.122
mdc|Other|2|20.61
mdc|Research|2|1.249
md|Required|3|2.309
migc|Lecture|1|2.17
migc|Other|1|70.719
migc|Research|1|12.83
mige|Lecture|1|0.12
mige|Other|1|4.32
mige|Research|1|20.026
mig|Lecture|1|12
mig|Other|1|1.681
mig|Research|1|5.4
```

Comment: You could just pipe the awk output to `sort` instead of using `| "sort"` inside the awk script which then causes awk to spawn a subshell to call `sort`.

Comment: @EdMorton Thank you, I actually had that and then changed it to what the OP uses because I did not know what would be better. Has using this inside awk a negative impact?

Comment: It just uses more resources and is a bit harder to maintain, e.g. if you add some other leg that produces output you have to remember to also add `| "sort"` to that too, and tightly couples the awk script to the shell and the other Unix command, `sort` so if you decided to run the script on, say, Windows then you'd have to modify the script.